# how to integrate wordpress users with vbulletin users

Tags: php, wordpress, import, integration, vbulletin

**i have my site in wordpress which has a vbulletin forum now i want that when i create user in wordpress 
it will automatically create user in vbulletin.
also when a user login with wordpress account it wil automatically login in vbulletin and able to post
  (maintaining session between wp to vbulletin)
i have tried a plugin says "VBsso" bt it work vice vrsa..:(  it will integrate vbulletin users to wordpress means i have to create vbulletin user and have to login in vbulletin bt i  dont want that...:(
i need wp to vb ..

plzz suggest me some plugin or some code or the way how to do that...??
any idea or suggestion will helps me a lot..thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [obscureclouddon's mod](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=296819), as an alternative to vbSSO.
[(an other link here)](http://wp-vb-bridge.obscurecloud.com/features-2)

It seems to be a good choice, since it has features you need :

> WordPress->vB features:
>
> *Registration sync – new users created on WP are automatically created on vB
>
> vBulletin ->Wordpress features *NEW*
>
> *Registration sync – new users created on vB are automatically created on WP

The bad things are :

- this modification is in beta stage
- free version has limited features, the pro version is, IMHO, expensive... (but it could worth the cost..)

Comment: thanks for your answer niak...:) i knew about this plugin bt i cant buy the full version. because this exceed the budget of my overall project.. if you ll found nulled version link or ny other solutin then plzz let me 9 it will b a gr8 help for me.